# Windows Mobile 6.5 Today Plugin

Tags: windows-mobile

Does anyone know how to develop a Today Plugin for the new Today screen on Windows Mobile 6.5? Like the [Titanium Weather Plugin](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=487090)?

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely not finding anything because your looking for the wrong name.  The new home screen plugin's are not called 'Today Plugin'.  They are called 'Widgets'.

The new widget system is written on top of the old today plugin's, and is itself a today screen plugin.  The widgets build build using HTML, CSS and javascript.

Check out [Getting started with widgets on Windows Mobile 6.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsmobile/archive/2009/06/04/getting-started-with-widgets-on-windows-mobile-6-5.aspx) article at the [Windows Mobile Developer Centre](http://developer.windowsmobile.com/).

Comment: I read that blog post before, and it doesn't say anything about Today. Also in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd721906.aspx nothing about today is mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want.  If you want to develop a today screen plugin, then it's the same as WM5 and WM6.  Nothing has changed.  But a today plugin will not install into the new today screen in WM6.5, which is itself just a today plugin that takes over the whole screen and exposes it's own plugin system called widgets.